# Find Document then Update Metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am trying to apply a bunch of metadata to a bunch of files in SPO. Using Find-PnPFile I can find the files in the subfolders. What I cannot figure out is how to pass the results of the Find-PnPFile back to Set-PnPListItem to set the values of the documents. I don't have the Identity of the file. What would be AMAZING is if there is a way to do this in a batch so I don't have to update every item one after another. It just feels like there should be a way to pass an array of document IDs and the value I want to set.

```
$updatefiles = Find-PnPFile -Folder "Documents/$($_.Name)" -Match "*"
foreach ($file in $updatefiles){
  Set-PnPListItem -List "Documents" -Values @"MMSField"="foo|bar|$($folder.Name)"} -Identity <<HELP>>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$childItems = Get-ChildItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderURL;
foreach($childItems in $childItems)
{
    Set-PnPListItem -List "Documents" -Values @"MMSField"="foo|bar|$($folder.Name)"} -Identity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of document library metadata as a list. This is what I use:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url $siteURL -UseWebLogin
$DocLibName = "<NameOfDocLib>"
$Allfiles = Get-PnPListItem -List $DocLibName
foreach( $file in $Allfiles)
{
    if($file.FieldValues.<Existing_x0020_Column> -eq "<Some Value>"){
        Set-PnPListItem -List $DocLibName -Identity $file.Id -Values @{"Column_x0020_Key" = "New Value"; "Second_x0020_Column_x0020_Key" = "New Value"}
    }
}
```

Connect-PnPOnline: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps

Get-PnPListItem: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps

Set-PnPListItem: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: As the question states, I need to use `Find-PnPFiles` I cannot enumerate every file in the library.

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact you cannot enumerate every file. Still you need to access the list item, and not the file. PnP handles them as two separate things. You cannot get the file, then use that object to update the list. The link I provided for Get-PnPListItem outlines how to get by ID.

Answer (score 0):

To set metadata of an existing file, use:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing"
$ListName = "Branding"
$SiteRelativeURL = "/Branding/Technical Design.docx"
$CreatedBy= "Salaudeen@crescent.com"
$Title = "New Design Document V2.docx"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

#Get the File from SharePoint
$File = Get-PnPFile -Url $SiteRelativeURL -AsListItem

#Update document properties
Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $File.Id -Values @{"Title" = $Title; "Author" = $CreatedBy}
```

Source: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/07/sharepoint-online-update-document-metadata-using-powershell.html#ixzz6NdSy9ZJE